# Watchconnectivity Example Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, watch, watchos-2

I've looked everywhere including the official documentation for a good example of send and reply messaging for Watch OS2 connectivity, even the official docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:). However, none give a nice example of a real call, or really explains what information is being returned, and where from, and then how to access is. Can someone direct me a bit?